# Using custom manager for many-to-many relations?

Tags: django

I have two classes (`Book` and `Question`) that are linked by a ManyToMany relationship. In particular, I typically call `book.questions.all()` to get all the questions in a book. Now, for my `Question` class, I have a custom manager `active_objects`, which basically only return questions that are active. What I'm trying to do is when I call `book.questions.all()`, I only want to return the active questions of the book using my custom manager.

I was looking at previous SO questions which recommended using `base_manager_name` but this doesn't seem to work for me. Upon checking the documentation, they said `base_manager_name` does not work for ManyToMany relationships (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/). Does anyone have a good way to do this?

```
class Question(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    active_objects = CustomManager() # custom manager.

    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name='questions')

    class Meta:
        base_manager_name = 'active_objects'

class Book(models.Model):
    pass
```

Comment: might you not be better off using filters when making those sorts of query? that is what they are for, is there a reason to go to this?

Comment: The main thing is because I have legacy code that currently use the `book.questions.all()` , whereas the custom manager is a new addition. I was hoping I could make a single change that affects the behaviour of all the lines of code. But I suppose using queries might be more explicit?

Comment: it would be less mysterious to a future maintainer why .all() was not behaving as .all() would normally be expected to behave if you were to use filters, yes.

Comment: That's an excellent point, and you are right. Thanks so much.